# How to support both api and web interface data interaction with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Im having major trouble separating api calls for our mobile app and for web interface, basically code is the same but the responses should be different (html as for web and json for api calls from app)

So right now I have routing like this:

```
  app.post('/post', auth.needed, posts.create)
  app.post('/addPost', posts.createJson)
```

first is used for web app and second one for

BUT the logic inside "posts.create" is the same, its basically uploading image and saves post to db, right now I have duplicated code and seeking for structuring advice how to do this properly and what is the best practice for similar situations
Thanks!

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var post= new Post(req.body)
  post.user = req.user
  //custom logic 
  post.uplSave(req.files.image, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.redirect('/posts/'+post._id)
    }
  }
}

exports.createJson = function (req, res) {
  var post = new Post(req.body)
  post.user = req.user
  //custom logic 
  post.uplSave(req.files.image, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      res.json({
        data: post,
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you can benefit from using [`res.format`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.format), so you can re-use your handler:

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var post  = new Post(req.body);
  post.user = req.user;
  post.uplSave(req.files.image, function (err) {
    if (err)
      return res.send(500); 
    res.format({
      default : function() {
        res.redirect('/posts/' + post._id);
      },
      json    : function() {
        res.json({ data : post });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

If a client explicitly tells the server that it wants a JSON response (using an `Accept: application/json` header), the server will return JSON. Otherwise (the `default` case) it will generate a redirect.

Since this depends on a client doing The Right Thing™, which might not be the case in your situation, another solution would be to create a [partial function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions) for your handler, passing the return type as a fixed argument:

```
app.post('/post', auth.needed, posts.create.bind(posts, 'default'));
app.post('/addPost', posts.create.bind(posts, 'json'));

// your handler would look like this:
exports.create = function(type, req, res) {
  ...
  if (type === 'json')
    return res.json(...);
  return res.redirect(...);
};
```

Comment: Accept: application/json
but what if application submits not only json data buy images/files/etc?

partial solution looks good though! thanks

Comment: @Leg0 `Accept` says "I'm willing to *receive* JSON as a response". Submitting data is something else and governed by the `Content-Type` header in the request.

Comment: Oh, my bad ;)
Thanks for the response